# Valgrind blocks lost, where to free?

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

I am trying to do a program which will be able to multiply and add matrix expressions with operator preference and so on.
I completed the program and it works, however I got a few errors in valgrind after completion. It is clear that this is because of bad usage of free() near the pointer to next matrix. But I am not able to work out how to do it correctly. Could somebody please help me, I will be very grateful for that.

**Here is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "files.h"
struct MatrixObject *matrix;


struct MatrixObject{
    size_t rows; 
    size_t columns;
    int *numbers;
    struct MatrixObject *pointToNext;
    char sign;
};

struct MatrixObject *newMatrixObject (size_t n, size_t m) {

    struct MatrixObject *retVal = malloc (sizeof (struct MatrixObject));
    if (retVal == NULL)
        return NULL;

    retVal->numbers = malloc (n * m * sizeof (int*));
    if (retVal->numbers == NULL) {
        free (retVal);
        return NULL;
    }

    retVal->pointToNext = malloc(sizeof(struct MatrixObject*));
    if (retVal->pointToNext == NULL) {
        free (retVal);
        return NULL;
    }


    retVal->rows = n;
    retVal->columns = m;
    return retVal;
}

struct MatrixObject* getMatrixArray(){
    struct MatrixObject *object;
    int m, n;   
    if(scanf("%d %d", &n, &m) != 2){
        errorHandle();
    }
    if(n<0 || m<0){
        errorHandle();
    }

    object = newMatrixObject(n, m);
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<m;j++){
            if(fscanf(stdin, "%d", &(object->numbers[(i*m)+j]))!=1){
                errorHandle();
            }
        }
    }

    char temp;
    int res;
    while((res=fscanf(stdin, "%c", &temp))!=EOF){
        if(res!=1){
            errorHandle();
        }
        if(temp == '*' || temp == '+' || temp == '-'){
            object->sign = temp;
            object->pointToNext = getMatrixArray();
            return object;
        }

    }

    object->sign = 0;
    object->pointToNext = 0;
    return object;
}

void multiplyMatrix(struct MatrixObject *matrix1, struct MatrixObject *matrix2){
    int newColumns = matrix2->columns;
    int newRows = matrix1->rows;
    int* newNumbers = malloc(newColumns * newRows * sizeof(*newNumbers));
    int counter = 0;
    if(matrix1->columns != matrix2->rows){
        errorHandle();
    }


    for(int i = 0;i<newRows;i++){
        for(int k = 0;k<newColumns;k++){


            int sum = 0;

            for(int j = 0;j<matrix1->columns;j++){
                sum+= ((matrix1->numbers)[(i*matrix1->columns)+j]) * ((matrix2->numbers)[(j*matrix2->columns)+k]);
            }       
            newNumbers[counter] = sum;
            counter++;
        }
    }   
    struct MatrixObject mat = *matrix2;
    free(matrix2->numbers);
    free(matrix2);
    matrix1->pointToNext = mat.pointToNext;
    matrix1->sign = mat.sign;


    free(matrix1->numbers);
    matrix1->numbers = newNumbers;
    matrix1->columns = newColumns;
    matrix1->rows = newRows;

}

void addMatrix(struct MatrixObject *matrix1, struct MatrixObject *matrix2, char sign){
    if(matrix1->columns != matrix2->columns || matrix1->rows != matrix2->rows){
        errorHandle();
    }
    int columns = matrix1->columns;
    int rows = matrix2->rows;
    int* newNumbers = malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(*newNumbers));

    for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<columns;j++){
            if(sign == '+'){
                newNumbers[i*columns + j] = matrix1->numbers[i*columns + j] + matrix2->numbers[i*columns + j];
            }else{
                newNumbers[i*columns + j] = matrix1->numbers[i*columns + j] - matrix2->numbers[i*columns + j];
            }
        }
    }


    struct MatrixObject mat = *matrix2;
    free(matrix2->numbers);
    free(matrix2);
    matrix1->pointToNext = mat.pointToNext;
    matrix1->sign = mat.sign;

    free(matrix1->numbers);
    matrix1->numbers = newNumbers;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct MatrixObject *actualMatrix;
    matrix = getMatrixArray();
    actualMatrix = matrix;
    while(actualMatrix->pointToNext != 0){
        if(actualMatrix->sign == '*'){
            multiplyMatrix(actualMatrix, actualMatrix->pointToNext);

        }   
        else{
            actualMatrix = actualMatrix->pointToNext;
        }
    }

    printMatrix(matrix);

    actualMatrix = matrix;
    while(actualMatrix->pointToNext != 0){
        if(actualMatrix->sign == '+' || actualMatrix->sign == '-'){
            addMatrix(actualMatrix, actualMatrix->pointToNext, actualMatrix->sign);
        }
    }

    printMatrix(matrix);    
    return 0;
}
```

**Here is output from my valgrind:**

```
==30650== 
==30650== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30650==     in use at exit: 88 bytes in 6 blocks
==30650==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 11 frees, 2,416 bytes allocated
==30650== 
==30650== Searching for pointers to 6 not-freed blocks
==30650== Checked 65,936 bytes
==30650== 
==30650== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==30650==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30650==    by 0x400C59: newMatrixObject (main.c:32)
==30650==    by 0x400D0F: getMatrixArray (main.c:54)
==30650==    by 0x40133F: main (main.c:177)
==30650== 
==30650== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 6
==30650==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30650==    by 0x400C59: newMatrixObject (main.c:32)
==30650==    by 0x400D0F: getMatrixArray (main.c:54)
==30650==    by 0x400DC3: getMatrixArray (main.c:71)
==30650==    by 0x40133F: main (main.c:177)
==30650== 
==30650== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 6
==30650==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30650==    by 0x400C59: newMatrixObject (main.c:32)
==30650==    by 0x400D0F: getMatrixArray (main.c:54)
==30650==    by 0x400DC3: getMatrixArray (main.c:71)
==30650==    by 0x400DC3: getMatrixArray (main.c:71)
==30650==    by 0x40133F: main (main.c:177)
==30650== 
==30650== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 6
==30650==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30650==    by 0x400C59: newMatrixObject (main.c:32)
==30650==    by 0x400D0F: getMatrixArray (main.c:54)
==30650==    by 0x400DC3: getMatrixArray (main.c:71)
==30650==    by 0x400DC3: getMatrixArray (main.c:71)
==30650==    by 0x400DC3: getMatrixArray (main.c:71)
==30650==    by 0x40133F: main (main.c:177)
==30650== 
==30650== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30650==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 4 blocks
==30650==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30650==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30650==    still reachable: 56 bytes in 2 blocks
==30650==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30650== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==30650== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==30650== 
==30650== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Here is some info for number lines:**

```
32: retVal->pointToNext = malloc(sizeof(struct MatrixObject*));
54: object = newMatrixObject(n, m);
71: object->pointToNext = getMatrixArray();
177:matrix = getMatrixArray();
```

Comment: `retVal->numbers = malloc (n * m * sizeof (int*));` --> `retVal->numbers = malloc (n * m * sizeof (int));`, `retVal->pointToNext = malloc(sizeof(struct MatrixObject*));` --> `retVal->pointToNext = NULL;`

Comment: the number of heap memory allocations must match the number of calls to `free()`  Currently there are 6 more allocations than there are `free()`s  Fix that problem and the memory leaks will go away

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks a lot man, that was leak I was looking for, you saved me a few another hours of solving this. I owe you one :)

Answer (score 0):

The first that I see is

```
struct MtrixObject *newMatrixObject (size_t n, size_t m) {

//...

retVal->pointToNext = malloc(sizeof(struct MatrixObject*));
if (retVal->pointToNext == NULL) {
    free (retVal);
    return NULL;
}
```

The retVal's Number was never free in the error checking block. Remember that freeing a struct doesn't free any variables inside that was initialized by malloc

In your main, matrix or actualMatrix wasn't free.
It looks like you are creating a default matrix, actualMatrix, and editing it then setting a pointer, pointToNext, to point the the edited matrix. Afterward, you are setting the actualMatrix back to default matrix. (Is this a LinkedList I'm seeing here?)

This mean you have a chain of matricies that are not free at the end. You should probably try

```
struct MatrixObject *temp;
while (matrix != NULL) {
    temp = matrix.pointToNext;
    free(matrix);
    matrix = temp;
}
```

This will go through all the matrix after that first matrix and free them.

Note that I have no idea what printMatrix does as it was never in your code. It could be that you free the matrices in there.

And one last comment, because you are calling errorHandle() in methods, there is a high chance if there are some errors, you are not freeing some mallocs

```
void multiplyMatrix(struct MatrixObject *matrix1, struct MatrixObject *matrix2){
    int newColumns = matrix2->columns;
    int newRows = matrix1->rows;
    int* newNumbers = malloc(newColumns * newRows * sizeof(*newNumbers));
    int counter = 0;
    if(matrix1->columns != matrix2->rows){
        errorHandle();
    }
//...
```

Here, errorHandle was called, but there is almost no way for you too free newNumbers as it was never passed in as a reference. This means that it will just float around and never get clean.

I recommend allocating for newNumbers after the errorHandle

Comment: Thanks a lot for contributing, actually my problem here was solved by simply setting value of retVal->pointToNext to NULL (as mentioned above). But now I can see all these other potential errors and bad practices in my code. I am glad you pointed that out, I will try to make it right in my next piece of code.